# Is there any way to add outline support to gedit to make it more usable for coding?

Tags: gedit, programming, text-editor

Geany for example has a sidebar with a "symbols" section showing functions and variables.

Comment: Maybe try a different program like MS Visual Studio Code or Sublime text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can install a plugin to do this.

In a terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-source-code-browser-plugin
```

Restart gedit, and from the menu select *Edit > Preferences > Plugins* and ensure *Source Code Browser* is ticked.

Now you will also have a *Source Code* option for the sidebar (*View > Side Panel* if it's currently hidden), that looks like:

[image: Gedit with Source Code sidebar]

Comment: Nice answer. Works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have voting rights yet.

Comment: I have voting rights now. Answer upvoted, as per my implied promise.